# What is a formal statement of the Dining Philosopher's Problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

(The dining philosopher's problem is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).)

I'm having trouble understanding whether or not the philosopher's act simultaneously. Do they all take one action simultaneously, then take their next action simultaneously? Or do they takes turns taking one action?

Is there a formal statement of the problem somewhere or a reduction of it to something that can be stated more rigorously?

Comment: The dining philosophers problem involves acquiring and releasing resources over time, and falls under the "concurrent/parallel programming" umbrella. The formal tools for dealing with such problems exist, but are not widely known/used because (in my opinion) they are very cumbersome. There are some nice papers by Lamport and Dijkstra about how to reason formally in these systems, if you would like to poke around.

Comment: However, in most situations like this, you should assume that each philosopher acts arbitrarily - they will wait an arbitrary amount of time before doing something, and if two philosophers try to (for example) pick up a fork at once, the tie is broken arbitrarily - one wins, one loses. Another reasonable assumption would be for ties to be broken by each backing off and resetting, and trying again at some (arbitrary) time in the future.

Comment: There are various possible ways to formulate the problem of the dining philosophers. They could take actions simultaneously, sequentially in turn, or in an arbitrary sequence. Depending on how you define _when_ the actions occur, you may have to adjust _what_ the actions are. You have seen some particular formulation, and only someone who has seen the same formulation can tell you what it says.